# Show that projections of element on orthogonal subspaces are summable.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{H_i: i \in I\}$ be a collection of closed orthogonal subspaces such that

$$H = \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i:= \overline{\sum_{i \in I} H_i}$$
where the closure is the norm-closure. I.e. $H$ is the inner orthogonal direct sum of these orthogonal subspaces.

Given $i \in I$, consider the orthogonal projection $p_i: H \to H_i$. If $x \in H$, is it true that
$$x= \sum_{i \in I} p_i(x)$$

Here the sum is considered to be in the norm-topology.

I don't have really much progress on this problem (I'm not even sure it's true!). I tried to show that $\sum_i p_i(x)$ converges by showing that $\sum_i \| p_i(x) \|^2 < \infty$ but could not even succeed at this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This easily follows from the following theorem:

> Let $(q_j)_{j \in J}$ be an increasing net of projections on the
> Hilbert space $H$. Then this net is strongly convergent to the
> projection of $H$ onto $$\overline{\bigcup_{j \in J} q_j(H)}$$

For a reference, see [1] theorem 4.1.2.

Let us see how this implies the theorem:

Given a finite subset $F \subseteq I$, put $p_F:= \sum_{i \in F} p_i$. Then note that
$$\overline{\bigcup_{F \subseteq I} p_F(H)}= H$$

So the net $p_F$ converges strongly to the identity function on $H$, that is
$$x= \sum_{i\in I} p_i(x)$$
for all $x \in H$.

---

[1] Murphy, G. J. (2014). C*-algebras and operator theory. Academic press.